# Using ways table features of OpenStreetMap data

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting

I have made this web-app `http://160.75.133.173/openWebApp/routing.jsp`
Users just have to click two points to figure out the shortest possible route available connecting them. I am using OSM data and pgrouting extension in postgresql.

But the OSM ways table is missing any feature which could be used to rank the roads (like Highways, one-lane, two-lane etc, or any sort of ranking depending upon road's width or any other feature).

How do I deal with questions like "I don't want the shortest route but the route using Highways only or as much Highways as possible", using OSM data?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you need to tweak the osm2pgrouting style to get a more detailed import:
http://pgrouting.org/docs/tools/osm2pgrouting.html

Comment: Thx dear! That was a great clue.
All I did was modified (/usr/share/osm2pgrouting/mapconfig.xml) file and added some more type and corresponding classes and then reimported my .osm data using osm2pgrouting command. I took the help of (/usr/share/osm2pgsql/default.style) file to add available types. 
From where can I get an extended form of mapconfig.xml file (default is https://github.com/pgRouting/osm2pgrouting/blob/master/mapconfig.xml) to just import everything into my db?
Thx. 
Zia